# open + edit html file on ckeditor

Tags: php, html, mysql, save, ckeditor

I have made to show ckEditor work on my website.

[image]

This is code that I used to open ckeditor

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor"></textarea>
   <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><h1><a href="../../website/promo_email.php">Go Back</h1></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!---End of menu--->
    </div> <!---End of sidebar--->

</div> <!---End of wrapper --->

</body>

</html>
```

I have other email form which I want to open html file automatically so

if html file is this

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
   </HEAD>
<BODY>
   <H1>Hello World</H1> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to see when I open editor

[image]

Also is it possible to change the original html file if I save it through ckEditor?

Main problems is that I do not know how to OPEN the html and SAVE the html file when I edit in ckEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,
You can edit your .htm file..
First open it with word pad. of ms word file..
edit it
copy whole text into a notepad.(if you have opened it in ms word)
save the file as .htm instead of . txt